# Huawei - how to ASR statistics

Tags: sip, voip, telephony

Need information about how to get ASR (Answer-Seizure Ratio) with Huawei.

I heard, huawei recording CDR for full call and not record CDR per routing tries.

Example scenario:

```
- Incoming call
- Static routes: first try -> "Trunk 1", second try -> "Trunk 5"
```

If call success (connected to Trunk 1) - I have one record in CDR - this is OK

If call fail on Trunk 1, but success on Trunk 5 - I have only one record in CDR - this is not normal.

As I expected, must have two records, one for failed call (Trunk 1) and one for success  (Trunk 5)

Else, how can I count ASR statistics?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Call Fail'? A typical routing algorithm in a voice switch would search for the first non busy trunk in a group. If it finds that the first trunk it looks at is busy, this is not what would usually be called a 'Call Fail' scenario. Alternatively, if it sets up the call on a non busy trunk and the call fails for some reason, most switches will not automatically just try another call as this might be confusing for the end user (if they heard dial, ringing, failure tone of some sort, then more ringing).

Comment: Fail may be for some reasons: local (busy trunk) remote (recv call release from destination party). I study details about voice switch, some switches can provide this info, some not.

Comment: If the trunk is busy and there is another free one in the trunk group it should automatically select that and this should not be a call fail. If you get a call release message then this is definitely a call fail.

Comment: Yes Mick, I mean if we have two separate carrier trunk group. First carrier trunk group is busy, call engine try next. This case we have no any CDR record for a first failed trie.